# SLDS icon not appearing in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system, svg-icon

Script 1: Does not Work

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds221, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css')}"/>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds221, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#email')}"></use>
    </svg>
</apex:page>
```

I can't see any icon on my page.
However when I remove stylesheet reference it renders fine. What am I missing

Script 2: This Works (Removed slds-static reference)

```
<apex:page >
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds221, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#email')}"></use>
    </svg>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 25):

1. You don't need to add lightning css as static resource. Just include this tag on top of your VF page: `<apex:slds />`.
2. Pass the icon reference directly as shown below:

   ```
    /apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity
   ```

Example:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity">
</use>
```

Comment: I cant still make it work, is any special tag needed? I already have <apex:slds /> and <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">   and page tag looks <apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">   body tag: <body class="slds-scope">  any ideas what i am missing

Comment: it works, i just add /apexpages/slds/latest/ . If i copy directly from slds website it does not work .

Comment: Although using the absolute path to the assets works now, if ever the location of the SLDS assets moves, these paths will 404. That's why the recommended method is to use `!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '…asset path…')`

Comment: The 'xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ' part in 'use' tag fixed the error.

Answer (score 5):

The current correct method to reference images and icons is to use the `!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '…asset path…')` method [as shown in this Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system/units/lightning-design-system5).

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-opportunity" title="Description of icon when needed">
    <svg class="slds-icon slds-page-header__icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <use 
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity')}"
        />
    </svg>
</span>
```

The asset path to enter as the second argument can be determined several ways.

- If the asset you want is included in the Lightning Design System Component Blueprint HTML you're using, just take the `xlink:href` value and remove the leading slash `/`.
- Another away is [downloading the Lightning Design System ZIP](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/) from the Design System site. The folder structure within the ZIP appears to be the same as the paths to the hosted assets. At least that's how I figure it out :)
- Finally, for icons, the [linked Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system/units/lightning-design-system5), also provides a method.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but this code works for me:

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-announcement"> 
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#announcement"></use>
    </svg>   
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Announcement</span>
</span>
```

You don't necessarily need 'svg' in your static resource instead you can use a  category sprite and choose appropriate icon as mentioned in above answer.
However you need to add:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

to your html tags(svg) as mentioned in 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_icons.htm